# Apache Ignite support for java 17

Tags: java, ignite, in-memory

Does apache ignite 2.14.0 work with java 17?

Tried running a java 17 application which uses apache ignite 2.14.0 and this error occured:
[Error while running java 17 application using which uses apache 2.14.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq5Kr.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The documentation suggests it does, see [Ignite Quick Start Guide for Java](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java). Otherwise provide a [mre] and provide the error **as text**. Please do not use screenshots.

Comment: @StephenDarlington: I don't think the OCR did quite right. "19 rammen Frames onitted" is humorous at least, though ...

Comment: @StephenDarlington please do not use OCR to provide information that the OP should provide themself (especially as there were errors in the OCR).

Comment: Fair enough. I thought it was an improvement but yeah, maybe the OCR errors made it worse.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it does. As [the doc says](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java#running-ignite-with-java-11-or-later), use the following JVM options:

```
--add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Or, use `ignite.sh` / `ignite.bat` scripts, which do this for you.

Comment: This worked thanks for sharing. 

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java#running-ignite-with-java-11-or-later

Answer (score 0):

Here's the spring-boot-maven-plugin JVM arguments configuration I'm using with Ignite & Java17.

```
                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <jvmArguments>
                            --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
                            --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
                            --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
                            --add-opens=java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED
                            --add-opens=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED
                            --add-opens=java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects=ALL-UNNAMED
                            --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
                            --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
                            --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                            --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                        </jvmArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```